# Why did Hattori Hanzo break his oath?

Tags: character, analysis, kill-bill

In the **Kill Bill** movie franchise, Hattori Hanzo breaks his 28 year old oath and makes the best sword in his life for Beatrice Kiddo.

There was no indication in the movies that Hanzo knew Bill. Then why did he break his oath and help Beatrice Kiddo just when she told him that she wanted to kill Bill?

What's the specialty about her that makes Hanzo help her?

Comment: I think he took the oath because he didn't want to design tools for killing.
And I assume he breaks it because that's just the affect The Bride seems to have on everyone, which you'll notice when you see Vol2.

Comment: "There was no indication in the movies that Hanzo knew Bill" I'm pretty sure there was. IIRC Bill was a former student.

Comment: Hanzo definitely knew Bill in some way. Kiddo merely described who she intended to kill and Hanzo wrote "Bill" on the window in response, so Hanzo knew exactly who Kiddo planned to kill just from her description.

Comment: THE BRIDE (ENGLISH)
          Because my vermin, is a former
          student of yours. And considering
          the student, I'd say you had a
          rather large obligation.

Hattori Hanzo goes to a dusty window, and writes the name,
"BILL" on it with his finger.

The blonde girl nods her head yes.
http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Kill-Bill-Volume-1-&-2.html

Answer (score 10):

Bill was Hattori Hanzo's former student. He used Hanzo's teachings for dishonorable purposes, causing Hanzo to retire.

But when Beatrix shows that she has the resolve to defeat Bill, Hanzo feels honorbound to make her a sword so she'd have a chance at winning.

**From ZacPensol at [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/2unnqt/kill_bill_why_did_hattori_hanz%C5%8D_take_the_oath_not/)**

> Considering that everyone seemed to make a big deal out of Beatrix having a Hanzo sword, and the emphasis put on Budd having one, I don't think that the rest of the team had them.
>
> Beatrix refers to Bill as a former pupil of Hanzo's, and Hanzo knows exactly who she's referring to. I always figured that Bill studied swordplay under Hanzo in a similar way that he studied martial arts from Pai Mei. However, Hanzo was perhaps put off by Bill's darker tendencies because Bill saw the swordsmanship as a means of creating violence instead of ending it.
>
> So whatever happened and Bill quit being Hanzo's apprentice and went on to form the DiVAS. Hanzo is a guy with connections most-certainly. I'm sure it's no stretch of the imagination that he eventually heard about - or even kept tabs on - Bill and how he'd become the leader of such a notorious assassination squad. His shame at having aided in creating not only weapons that kill people, but "creating" Bill as a deadly individual, lead him to retire in guilt so as not to ever create something or someone as horrible as Bill again.
>
> He, of course, breaks this oath when Beatrix shows up because, though he's hesitant to create another great sword that could so easily kill more people, in Beatrix he not only sees a lightness that was not in Bill, but a way to secure his heart and mind that the evil he'd helped create "Bill" would be brought to an end. Perhaps this wouldn't wipe free his guilt over Bill's former actions, but it would at least ease his mind to know that Bill's reign of terror was over.

Answer (score 1):

In the scene where The Bride is trying to get Hattari Hanzo to make her a sword she mentions a "former" pupil and he changes his mind, writing on the window Bill,which shows that Bill was a former student of Hattori Hanzo.

So Hattori hanzo knew Bill. Bill used Hattari Hanzo's teachings for evil, instead of belief and self defense.So Mr.Hanzo decided to make the sword for Beatrice.

Comment: Cant he defeat and even kill bill himself? if hanzo is such a good guy, then why use a girl?